# webpack simply bundle es6 syntax

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm writing React. I don't want to compile es6 to es5. As browsers already supported [es6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

It seems JS minification is not that mature. But it's fine. I only need to bundle the JS files.

I want to use `Object static methods` feature.

webpack version is 3.10.0.

There's error when I run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d`.

```
Hash: 84a44d953a9cf1e8e1f5
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 257ms
                Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./../public/bundle.js  3.53 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/App.jsx 636 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:8)

   5 | class App extends React.Component {
   6 | 
>  7 |   state = {
     |         ^
   8 |     name: "React"
   9 |   }
  10 |
```

Here the codes:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: "React"
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>Hello, I'm {this.state.name}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("main"))
```

Here's the webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: './../public/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react'],
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does it mean webpack 3.0 doesn't support es6 yet? Or I missed something?

Thanks for your time!

Updated:

According to @Xlee, the webpack.config.js should be:

```
...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties'],
          presets: ['react'],
        }
      }
    ]
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use Object static methods feature.

Actually the feature you wanna use is not ES6, it's called the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Simply drop a new babel plugin with `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`, and update babelrc(recommended)/webpack(babel loader) accordingly.

details here: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/#top

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Comment: ES7 has been released 2 years ago. *Class fields* are a proposal.

Comment: thanks for correction :]

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your state in the constructor:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "React"
        }
    }
}
```